Using variables in Class Attribute declarations in Python
I am using django-filters in a Python project. I need to be able to declare a list of fields, and for each field in the list declare a Filter object.
Currently I am inheriting the parent FilterSet in my custom class called FrameworkFilterSet' in order to define some generic fields that will be used in all FilterSet declarations (I have a FilterSet class for each module in my project, eg. Order, Contacts, Stock etc.)
This works fine, I end up with a created_by filter and an order_number filter.
class FrameworkFilterSet(FilterSet):

    created_by = ChoiceFilter(choices=get_users, label='Created By',empty_label=(''),
         widget=forms.Select(attrs={'placeholder':'created by', 'class': 'created_by__username form-select filter-form  border'}))

And this is an example of one of the modules' FilterSet declaration
class OrderFilter(FrameworkFilterSet):

    order_number = CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains', field_name='order_number', label='Order Number', 
        widget = Input(attrs={'placeholder':'order number', 'class': 'filter filter-form form-control  border'}))

What I am struggling with, is to be able to define a list of fields in say OrderFilter, and then use those field names to create some more FilterSets with slightly different attributes, but using the defined names.
For example, in OrderFilterSet:
multi_fields = ('order_number')

And then in FrameworkFilterSet:
(Psuedo code):
For each field in multi_fields:
    order_number = CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains', field_name='order_number', label='Order Number', 
            widget = Input(attrs={'placeholder':'order number', 'class': 'filter filter-form form-control  border'}))
    
    order_number_e = CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains', field_name='order_number', label='Order Number', exclude=True,
            widget = Input(attrs={'placeholder':'order number', 'class': 'filter filter-form form-control  border'}))

I have tried using __init__, but that is when the objects are created. I need to do this when the class is declared, not at object creation.

Please post a [mre], it's hard to tell what you're trying to do from these bits and pieces. If you want to define a class attribute at class definition time, just put it in the class definition outside a method.
